# How do I install SQLite on Android emulator / Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, emulation

I want to install a test database on the Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2015 Community for a Xamarin Forms project.

Can't find any instructions on how to do this.

(Also can't figure out how to access the Terminal on Android Emulator.)

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Stephen McAteer.

Comment: You don't install it, it's deployed as part of your app.  See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: Great. Thanks Jason.

Comment: Please also observe the release notes relating to Android 7 only allowing linking to NDK provided libraries potentially causing your app to crash on Android 7 - https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.1/

Comment: Thanks Alan. I'll take a look.

Comment: To open a shell for an Android device or emultaor, use `adb shell` cmmoand. Open a command prompt and navigate to your Android SDK platform tools directory, usually %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
(If your android SDK path is different, you can find the path by opening your Android SDK manager and the path is noted at the top)
Once in that directory, enter command `adb shell` and you are now at a terminal for the device (this assumes you only have one android device/sim connected).